# Find three numbers $a,b,c$ such that $33$ divides their product $abc$ but none of them is divisible by $33$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

- Find three numbers $a,b,c$ such that $33$ divides their product  $abc$ but none of them is divisible by $33$.

My answer is: $33,11,3$. Then $33$ divides their product  $abc$ but none of them is divisible by $33$.

Can you check? Thanks... Can you give another answer?

Comment: If $a=33$ it is divisible by $33$

Answer (score 1):

$a=1$, $b=3$ and $c=11$ is a solution. You can take all permutation of those also.

And I don't know how your solution works, since you take one to be $33$.

You can take also

$a = 3^k$, $b=3^n$ and $c=11^m$  or

$a = 3^k$, $b=11^n$ and $c=11^m$  or

$a = 11^k$, $b=3^n$ and $c=3^m$ or...

Comment: How about $$a=\prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{a_p}, b = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{b_p}, c = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{c_p}$$ and then you can have two of $a_3, b_3, c_3$ at least 1 and zero for the last, and $a_{11}>0$ if and only if $a_3=0$, $b_{11}>0$ if and only if $b_3=0$, and $c_{11}>0$ if and only if $c_3=0$. Similarly with two of $a_{11},b_{11},c_{11}$ at least 1 and the last zero, then the opposite for powers of 3.

Comment: Yeah..........@InterstellarProbe why don't you write it as an answer

Comment: @MariaMazur Then, you are answer is false?

Comment: Why.....................?